# Как правильно верстать баннер со скруглением?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть несколько вариантов как это сделать, хочу понять какой будет правильным. Например вставить background, вместе с нижней тенью. Второй вариант css рисовать полукруг и добавлять тень. Уверен что еще много вариантив. Как это сделать будет правильно? подскажите плз...

[image: Баннер]

Comment: Какие требования к баннеру? Адаптивность, возможность замены текста, цветов, картинки? Если никаких таких требований нет, то не вижу смысла мудрить и делать что-то сложнее чем тупо jpeg-картинка

Comment: текст статический, адаптивность нужна...а кроме картинки как можно еще сделать не в курсе?

Comment: Делайте jpeg-ом с width:100% белого контейнера и height:auto и не заморачивайтесь.

Answer (score 2):

Например с помощью border-radius.

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
.block {
  background:url(http://m.wsj.net/video/20140117/011714digitstechweek/011714digitstechweek_1280x720.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  height:90vh;
  border-radius:0 0 100% 100%;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```